# kinect extrinsic parameters

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to move the kinect on my turtlebot. the tf of the kinect will change and I want the new extrinsic parameters of the kinect. How can I calibrate this parameters?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110371/kinect-extrinsic-parameters/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The extrinsic parameters for `tf` related to kinect position on the turtlebot are present in `turtlebot_calibration.xacro` file. I use ROS fuerte, in my system this file is present at `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/urdf/`. Locate this file correspondingly for your system.

Using this file- x,y,z, yaw, pitch and roll of the kinect can be set.

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0